# I want to show all image preview but whenever I upload a new one the old one is gone

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem as my title said above. I have 4 input file type and it must divide into 4 button but whenever I try to upload a new one the old one preview is gone but it still in there. I use reactjs to make this.

Whenever **I try to search in here it always about multiple image upload preview**. But **what I try to do is one by one upload and preview it all**.

I already made a codesandbox in here : https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bardeen-q89rr?fontsize=14

Can someone help me to solve this? I do some trick as save it in localstorage but it still not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the state set or structure, depending on the point of view.

This is your initial state:

```
state = {
  form: {
    frontDesign: [],
    backDesign: [],
    leftDesign: [],
    rightDesign: []
  }
};
```

However, every time you update with a new value you are overriding the previous value

```
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      form: {
        frontDesign: [reader.result]
      }
    }));
```

Notice the `state` contains already the form object, you are setting a new state with only `form { frontDesign: value }` as above example.

You'd have either get rid of the form object wrapper or set the state in this way

```
  this.setState(state => ({
    form: {
      ...state.form,
      frontDesign: [reader.result]
    }
  }));
```

Notice the `...state.form` spread.

Let me know if further questions.

Comment: wow Thankyou it works, so if I just do what I did earlier it just change all the state before and turn the value to null? is what I think right about your explanation?